# Get name from database table to use in select statement instead of databasename

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a script that runs through databases with the word VLdata in the databasename. Since the database name and table name is different, I look in the sys login table to look for the login user that has the same name as the table name.

I.e the database name is for example W2595VLData but the table name is "showoffstudios.WgYr"

In all the databases there are a login user with the same name as the table name for the database.

When I run the script below i get the error message "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

I want the below SELECT @DB_LoginName statement to also only run through the databases with "VLData" in the name.

Because I need @DB_LoginName to be the table name and not the database name. So when looking in the database for the column .WgPaySlip it need to be for example W2595.showoffstudios.WgPaySlip.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%VLData% 
OPEN database_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN



SELECT @DB_LoginName = (select name as username
                        from sys.database_principals
                        where type not in ('A', 'G', 'R', 'X')
                        and sid is not null
                        and name != 'guest'
                        and name != 'dbo'
```

The original script: This gives me the error

Invalid object name '2544VLData.2544.WgRun'.
because the database name is changed and the table name has another name.

````
DECLARE @DB_LoginName varchar(200) 
DECLARE @Command nvarchar(MAX)

create table #PaySlips
(
    WgYr int,
    RunNo int,
    PaySlips int
);

create table #TotalNumber
(
    Firmanavn varchar(100),
    Lønnsslipper int,
    Sammenstillingsoppgaver int,
    Lønnsår int
);


DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.sysdatabases where name LIKE '%VLData%'
OPEN database_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    SELECT @DB_LoginName = LEFT(@DB_Name,CHARINDEX('VLData',@DB_Name)-1)

    SET @Command = 'declare @StartYear int, @EndYear int, @WgYr int, @RunNo int, @PaySlips int, @YearEnd int
                    set @StartYear = 2020
                    set @EndYear = 2020
                    declare WgRun_Cursor cursor for select WgYr, RunNo from ' + '[' + @DB_Name + '].' + '[' + @DB_LoginName + '].WgRun where WgYr >= @StartYear and WgYr <= @EndYear order by WgYr, RunNo
                    open WgRun_Cursor
                    fetch next from WgRun_Cursor into @WgYr, @RunNo
                    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    begin
                        set @PaySlips = isnull((select count (distinct EmpNo) from ' + '[' + @DB_Name + '].' + '[' + @DB_LoginName + '].WgPaySlip where WgYr = @WgYr and WgYr <= @EndYear and RunNo = @RunNo),0)
                        insert into #PaySlips values(@WgYr, @RunNo, @PaySlips)
                        fetch next from WgRun_Cursor into @WgYr, @RunNo
                    end
                    close WgRun_Cursor
                    deallocate WgRun_Cursor 
                    
                    declare WgYr_Cursor cursor for select WgYr from ' + '[' + @DB_Name + '].' + '[' + @DB_LoginName + '].WgYr where WgYr >= @StartYear and WgYr <= @EndYear order by WgYr
                    open WgYr_Cursor
                    fetch next from WgYr_Cursor into @WgYr
                    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    begin
                        set @PaySlips = isnull((select sum(PaySlips) from #PaySlips where WgYr = @WgYr),0)
                        set @YearEnd = isnull((select count (distinct EmpNo) from ' + '[' + @DB_Name + '].' + '[' + @DB_LoginName + '].WgYearEnd where WageYear = @WgYr),0)
                        insert into #TotalNumber values ((select top 1 Nm from ' + '[' + @DB_Name + '].' + '[' + @DB_LoginName + '].FrmData), @PaySlips, @YearEnd, @WgYr)
                        fetch next from WgYr_Cursor into @WgYr
                    end
                    close WgYr_Cursor
                    deallocate WgYr_Cursor'
        EXEC sp_executesql @Command

     FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DB_Name 
END

CLOSE database_cursor 
DEALLOCATE database_cursor

select * from #TotalNumber

drop table #PaySlips
drop table #TotalNumber ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are seeing multiple logins, or multiple instances of the same login.

Either add a top(1) as I've shown below, or probably better will be to re-write your code to handle each LoginName seperately.

```
SELECT @DB_LoginName = (select top(1) name as username
                        from sys.database_principals
                        where type not in ('A', 'G', 'R', 'X')
                        and sid is not null
                        and name != 'guest'
                        and name != 'dbo'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but I also found another trick I used  `SELECT @DB_LoginName = (SELECT Top 1 TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)` But this gave med 2544VLData.dbo.WgPaySlip. Is it possible in the SELECT statement to just read the information.schema.table from the active database that the cursor has in @DB_Name?